# Is using malloc() and free() a really bad idea on Arduino?

Tags: programming, sram, eeprom

The use of `malloc()` and `free()` seems pretty rare in the Arduino world. It is used in pure AVR C much more often, but still with caution.

Is it a really bad idea to use `malloc()` and `free()` with Arduino?

Comment: you'll run out of memory really fast otherwise, and if you know how much memory you'll use you might as well statically allocate it anyway

Comment: As usual, the right answer is "it depends." You haven't provided enough information to know for sure whether dynamic allocation is right for you.

Answer (score 51):

My general rule for embedded systems is to only `malloc()` large buffers and only once, at the start of the program, e.g., in `setup()`. The trouble comes when you allocate and de-allocate memory. Over a long run session, memory becomes fragmented and eventually an allocation fails due to lack of a sufficiently large free area, even though the total free memory is more than adequate for the request.

(Historical perspective, skip if not interested): Depending on the loader implementation, the only advantage of run-time allocation vs. compile-time allocation (intialized globals) is the size of the hex file. When embedded systems were built with off the shelf computers having all volatile memory, the program was often uploaded to the embedded system from a network or an instrumentation computer and the upload time was sometimes an issue. Leaving out buffers full of zeros from the image could shorten the time considerably.)

If I need dynamic memory allocation in an embedded system, I generally `malloc()`, or preferably, statically allocate, a large pool and divide it into fixed-size buffers (or one pool each of small and large buffers, respectively) and do my own allocation/de-allocation from that pool. Then every request for any amount of memory up to the fixed buffer size is honored with one of those buffers. The calling function doesn't need to know whether it's larger than requested, and by avoiding splitting and re-combining blocks we solve fragmentation. Of course memory leaks can still occur if the program has allocate/de-allocate bugs.

Update 02/16/23:

> I'm curious why the Arduino library's malloc implementation doesn't
> implement some coalescing of the free blocks like a full OS would.

That's interesting to think about, but let's first be clear that in C/C++, malloc() and free() are implemented as library functions at the application-level not the OS level, even in major OSes. And they are based on fragmenting the heap, just as the Arduinos' malloc() functions do.

Embedded systems, are relatively new, at least as an influential force in the design of OSes, languages, and libraries' design. Which is to say, programs that had to run "forever" without failing (other than, perhaps the OS itself) were outliers. Most programs we run on our desktops or (once upon a time) ran on mainframes, were started, processed a batch of data, and exited.

Secondly, the malloc()/free() method of memory allocation/deallocation was simple, where anticipating the sizes of memory requests was not; and some allocations are used briefly and returned, where some are kept for the duration of the run. How is a library designer to provide for coalescing currently free and newly deallocated memory with no knowledge of the allocate/deallocate usage and sizes of requests? The fixed-size buffer scheme I described above doesn't suffer the fragmentation problem that "malloc() an arbitrary number of bytes" scheme does. It is still limited to available memory but within that limitation, could meet the "run forever" requirement. There may be algorithms that split and coalesce memory, but probably only for a few - statistically predictable - patterns of allocation and deallocation.

Update 02/18/23:

@edgarbonet points out that Arduino's `free()` does try to coalesce free blocks. This is a good example of an algorithm that works for certain cases: Properly done, it would work for "last-out / first-in" cases, and to some extent for some other cases.

The trouble is, most of our use patterns are not very regular, if they're regular at all. An alogrithm that does no splitting, but merely allocates & deallocates fixed-size pieces (rather like loaning library books) can still run out of memory but won't end up with fragmented resources. In fact, because it doesn't split, it *will* need more memory to meet the same random-sized requests than even a coalescing `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: Another historical note, this quickly led to the BSS segment, which allowed a program to zero its own memory for initialization, without slowly copying the zeros during program load.

Comment: I'm curious why the Arduino library's malloc implementation doesn't implement some coalescing of the free blocks like a full OS would.

Comment: @vasilescur: The AVR implementation of `malloc()`/`free()` does coalesce adjacent free blocks.

Answer (score 21):

I have taken a look at the algorithm used by `malloc()`, from avr-libc,
and there seems
to be a few usage patterns that are safe from the point of view of heap
fragmentation:

### 1. Allocate only long-lived buffers

By this I mean: allocate all you need at the beginning of the program,
and never free it. Of course, in this case, you could as well use static
buffers...

### 2. Allocate only short-lived buffers

Meaning: you free the buffer before allocating anything else. A
reasonable example might look like this:

```
void foo()
{
    size_t size = figure_out_needs();
    char * buffer = malloc(size);
    if (!buffer) fail();
    do_whatever_with(buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```

If there is no malloc inside `do_whatever_with()`, or if that function
frees whatever it allocates, then you are safe from fragmentation.

### 3. Always free the last allocated buffer

This is a generalization of the two previous cases. If you use the heap
like a stack (last in is first out), then it will behave like a stack
and not fragment. It should be noted that in this case it is safe to
resize the last allocated buffer with `realloc()`.

### 4. Always allocate the same size

This will not prevent fragmentation, but it is safe in the sense that
the heap will not grow larger than the maximum *used* size. If all your
buffers have the same size, you can be sure that, whenever you free one
of them, the slot will be available for subsequent allocations.

Comment: Pattern 2 should be avoided as it adds cycles for malloc() and free() when this can be done with "char buffer[size];" (in C++). I would also like to add the anti-pattern "Never from an ISR".

Answer (score 19):

Typically, when writing Arduino sketches, you will avoid dynamic allocation (be it with `malloc` or `new` for C++ instances), people rather use global -or `static`- variables, or local (stack) variables.

Using dynamic allocation can lead to several problems:

- memory leaks (if you lose a pointer to a memory you previously allocated, or more likely if you forget to free the allocated memory when you don't need it anymore)
- heap fragmentation (after several `malloc`/`free` calls) where the heap grows bigger thant the actual amount of memory allocated currently

In most situations I have faced, dynamic allocation was either not necessary, or could be avoided with macros as in the following code sample:

**MySketch.ino**

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 32
#include "Dummy.h"
```

**Dummy.h**

```
class Dummy
{
    byte buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ...
};
```

Without `#define BUFFER_SIZE`, if we wanted `Dummy` class to have a non-fixed `buffer` size, we would have to use dynamic allocation as follows:

```
class Dummy
{
    const byte* buffer;

    public:
    Dummy(int size):buffer(new byte[size])
    {
    }

    ~Dummy()
    {
        delete [] bufer;
    }
};
```

In this case, we have more options than in the first sample (e.g. use different `Dummy` objects with different `buffer` size for each), but we may have heap fragmentation issues.

Note the use of a destructor to ensure dynamically allocated memory for `buffer` will be freed when a `Dummy` instance is deleted.

Answer (score 10):

I disagree with people who think you shouldn't use it or it is generally unnecessary. I believe it can be dangerous if you don't know the ins and outs of it, but it is useful. I do have cases where I don't know (and shouldn't care to know) the size of a structure or a buffer (at compile time or run time), especially when it comes to libraries I send out into the world. I agree that if you're application is only dealing with a single, known structure, you should just bake in that size at compile time.

Example: I have a serial packet class (a library) that can take arbitrary length data payloads (can be struct, array of uint16_t, etc.). On the sending end of that class you simply tell the Packet.send() method the address of the thing you wish to send and the HardwareSerial port through which you wish to send it. However, on the receiving end I need a dynamically allocated receive buffer to hold that incoming payload, as that payload could be a different structure at any given moment, depending on the application's state, for instance. IF I'm only ever sending a single structure back and forth, I'd just make the buffer the size it needs to be at compile time. But, in the case where packets may be different lengths over time, malloc() and free() are not so bad.

I've run tests with the following code for days, letting it loop continuously, and I've found no evidence of memory fragmentation. After freeing the dynamically allocated memory, the free amount returns to its previous value.

```
// found at learn.adafruit.com/memories-of-an-arduino/measuring-free-memory
int freeRam () {
    extern int __heap_start, *__brkval;
    int v;
    return (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval);
}

uint8_t *_tester;

while(1) {
    uint8_t len = random(1, 1000);
    Serial.println("-------------------------------------");
    Serial.println("len is " + String(len, DEC));
    Serial.println("RAM: " + String(freeRam(), DEC));
    Serial.println("_tester = " + String((uint16_t)_tester, DEC));
    Serial.println("alloating _tester memory");
    _tester = (uint8_t *)malloc(len);
    Serial.println("RAM: " + String(freeRam(), DEC));
    Serial.println("_tester = " + String((uint16_t)_tester, DEC));
    Serial.println("Filling _tester");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        _tester[i] = 255;
    }
    Serial.println("RAM: " + String(freeRam(), DEC));
    Serial.println("freeing _tester memory");
    free(_tester); _tester = NULL;
    Serial.println("RAM: " + String(freeRam(), DEC));
    Serial.println("_tester = " + String((uint16_t)_tester, DEC));
    delay(1000); // quick look
}
```

I haven't seen any sort of degradation in RAM or in my ability to allocate it dynamically using this method, so I'd say it's a viable tool. FWIW.

Comment: Your test code conforms to the usage pattern _2. Allocate only short-lived buffers_ I described in my previous answer. This is one of those few usage patterns known to be safe.

Comment: In other words, the problems will come up when you start sharing the processor with other *unknown* code - which is precisely the problem you think you are avoiding.  Generally, if you want something that will always work or else fail during linking, you make a fixed allocation of the maximum size and use it over and over again, for example by having your user pass it in to you in initialization.  Remember you are typically running on a chip where **everything** has to fit in 2048 bytes - maybe more on some boards but also maybe a lot less on others.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Yes, exactly. Just wanted to share.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It's because of the memory constraints that I believe dynamically allocating the buffer of only the size required in the moment is ideal. If the buffer isn't need during regular operation, the memory is available for something else. But, I see what you're saying: Allocate a reserved space so that something else doesn't take away the space you may need for the buffer. All great information and thoughts.

Comment: Dynamically allocating a buffer of only the size needed is risky, as if anything else allocates before you free it you can be left with fragmentation - memory that you can't re-use.  Also, dynamic allocation has tracking overhead.  Fixed allocation doesn't mean you can't multiply use the memory, it just means that you have to work the sharing into the design of your program.  For a buffer with purely local scope, you might also weigh use of the stack.  You haven't checked for the possibility of malloc() failing either.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Right, that chunk of code doesn't check if malloc() works or not. Then again, that chunk of code is using notoriously fat Arduino libraries and routines. :) Thanks for your insight. Very reasonable and valuable.

Comment: "it can be dangerous if you don't know the ins and outs of it, but it is useful." pretty much sums up all development in C/C++. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Using dynamic allocation (via `malloc`/`free` or `new`/`delete`) isn't inherently bad as such. In fact, for something like string processing (e.g. via the `String` object), it's often quite helpful. That's because many sketches use several small fragments of strings, which eventually get combined into a larger one. Using dynamic allocation lets you use only as much memory as you need for each one. In contrast, using a fixed-size static buffer for each one could end up wasting a lot of space (causing it to run out of memory much faster), although it depends entirely on the context.

With all of that being said, it's very important to make sure memory usage is predictable. Allowing the sketch to use arbitrary amounts of memory depending on run-time circumstances (e.g. input) can easily cause a problem sooner or later. In some cases, it might be perfectly safe, e.g. if you *know* the usage will never add up to much. Sketches can change during the programming process though. An assumption made early-on could be forgotten when something is changed later, resulting in an unforeseen problem.

For robustness, it's usually better to work with fixed-size buffers where possible, and design the sketch to work explicitly with those limits from the outset. That means any future changes to the sketch, or any unexpected run-time circumstances, should hopefully not cause any memory problems.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a really bad idea to use malloc() and free() with Arduino?

The short answer is yes. Below are the reasons why:

It is all about understanding what an MPU is and how to program within the constraints of the available resources. The Arduino Uno uses an [ATmega328p](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) MPU with 32KB ISP flash memory, 1024B EEPROM, and 2KB SRAM. That is not a lot of memory resources.

Remember that the 2KB SRAM is used for all global variables, string literals, stack and possible usage of the heap. The stack also needs to have head room for an ISR.

The [memory layout](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html) is:

[image: SRAM map]

Todays PC/laptops have more than 1.000.000 times the amount of memory. A 1 Mbyte default stack space per thread is not uncommon but totally unrealistic on an MPU.

An embedded software project has to do a resource budget. This is estimating  ISR latency, necessary memory space, compute power, instruction cycles, etc. There are unfortunately no free-lunches and hard real-time embedded programming is the most [difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOMO) of programming skills to master.

Comment: Amen to that: "[H]ard real-time embedded programming is the most difficult of programming skills to master."

Comment: Is the execution time of malloc always the same? I can imagine malloc taking more time as it searches further in the available ram for a slot that fits? This would be yet another argument (aside running out of ram) to not allocate memory on the go?

Comment: @Paul The heap algorithms (malloc and free) are typically not constant execution time, and not reentrant. The algorithm contains search and data structures that require locks when using threads (concurrency).

Comment: In light of the resource limitations of such small devices some would argue that the use of malloc/free as required for the scenarios is a much more efficient use of resources than pre allocating a bunch of fixed size buffers whose size must be large if being conservative (i.e. able to handle ALL scenarios). Lots of wasted allocation most of the time in that usage pattern methinks.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I know this is an old question but the more I read through the answers the more I keep coming back to an observation that seems salient.

### The Halting Problem Is Real

There seems to be a link with Turing's Halting Problem here.  Allowing dynamic allocation increases the odds of said 'halting' so the question becomes one of risk-tolerance. While it is convenient to wave off the possibility of `malloc()` failing and so forth, it is still a valid outcome.  The question the OP asks only appears to be about technique, and yes the details of the libraries used or the specific MPU do matter; the conversation turns towards reducing the risk of the program halting or any other abnormal end. We need to recognize the existence of environments that tolerate risk vastly differently.  My hobby project to display pretty colors on a LED-strip won't kill someone if something unusual happens but the MCU inside a heart-lung machine likely will.

### Hello Mr. Turing My Name is Hubris

For my LED-strip, I don't care if it locks up, I'll just reset it.  If I were on a heart-lung machine controlled by an MCU the consequences of it locking up or failing to operate are literally life and death, so the question about `malloc()` and `free()` should be split between how the intended program deals with the possibility of demonstrating Mr. Turing's famous problem. It can be easy to forget that it is a mathematical proof and to convince ourselves that if only we are clever enough we can avoid being a casualty of the limits of computation.

This question should have two accepted answers, one for those who are forced to blink when staring The Halting Problem in the face, and one for all others. While most uses of the arduino are likely not mission critical or life-and-death applications, the distinction is still there regardless of which MPU you may be coding.

Comment: I don't think the Halting problem applies in this specific situation considering the fact that heap usage isn't necessarily arbitrary. If used in a well-defined manner then heap usage becomes predictably "safe". The point of the Halting problem was figure out if it can be determined what happens to a necessarily arbitrary and not-so-well-defined algorithm. It really applies much more to programming in a broader sense and as-such I find it to be specifically not very relevant here. I don't even think it's relevant at all to be entirely honest.

Comment: I'll admit to some rhetorical exaggeration but the point is really if you want to guarantee behavior, using the heap implys a level of risk that is much higher than sticking to only using the stack.