# Slice string at “:”

Tags: serial, string

I need to slice a string (eg- 4:288:18464:288:4) at ":" into an array({4, 288, 18464, 288, 4}) I used the following code, but its giving only '4' in the serial monitor when "4:288:18464:288:4," is given to arduino.

```
void displayString(char* s)
{
  char* text = strtok(s,":");

  while(text != NULL){
  text = strtok(NULL,":");}
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        str = Serial.readStringUntil(',');
        str.toCharArray(text,99);
    }
  displayString(text);
Serial.println(text);
}
```

Comment: Do you know in advance how many substrings you expect from the original one?

Comment: Every string will contain 5 substring. But the number of strings will be different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `strtok` the way it should:

```
char* text = strtok(s,":");
while(text != NULL){
    text = strtok(NULL,":");
}
```

Your code just replaces, in `s`, all occurrences of `:` with `0` (i.e. a byte of value 0, not the ASCII value of `'0'`), thus terminating each substring.

At the end of `displayString(text)` call from `loop()`, `text` still points to the 1st character of the original string (in your post `4:288:18464:288:4`), but that string now terminates at the position of the first `:`, which explains why `Serial.println(text)` prints just `4`.

Now if you want to split the original string into an array of substrings, as asked in your question, you need to modify `displayString` this way:

```
// Maximum number of substrings expected
const int MAX_SUBSTRINGS = 5;
// Array of pointers to each substring after displayString() has been called
static char* substrings[MAX_SUBSTRINGS];

void displayString(char* s) {
    // First clear the array of substrings
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBSTRINGS; i++)
        substrings[i] = 0;
    // Now split the input string
    char* text = strtok(s,":");
    int i = 0;
    while (text != 0 && i < MAX_SUBSTRINGS) {
        // A toekn was found: append it to the array of substrings
        substrings[i++] = text;
        text = strtok(0,":");
    }
}
```

After calling `displayString(text)`, you can use its result in `loop()` as follows:

```
void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        str = Serial.readStringUntil(',');
        str.toCharArray(text,99);
    }
    displayString(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBSTRINGS; i++) {
        if (substrings[i] != 0)
            Serial.println(substrings[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that this will work **ONLY** if the original string contains no more than 5 substrings delimited by `:`. If the max number of substrings cannot be known at compile time, then you'll have to use dynamic allocation, [which is generally not a very good idea on embedded platforms](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/682/is-using-malloc-and-free-a-really-bad-idea-on-arduino/687#687).