# Simple compiler design help: Variable length arrays in Arduino?

Tags: arduino-due, compile

I'm trying to write a simple compiler in the Arduino language that I am making up for my lab.  The compiler will have to be able to turn a string like this:

```
"do command_one 3 times"
```

into a data structure that represents this:

```
<command_one>, <command_one>, <command_one>
```

it should also be able to turn something more complicated like this:

```
"do do c_one do c_two 2 times 2 times c_thr 2 times"
```

into a data structure that represents this:

```
<c_one> <c_two> <c_two> <c_one> <c_two> <c_two> <c_thr> <c_one>
                <c_two> <c_two> <c_one> <c_two> <c_two> <c_thr>
```

Another function will then read the commands out one by one.

These examples show all of the functionality that I would want from the compiler.

I'm having design issues for the compiler that I want to create.  Initially, I just wanted to do some string manipulation and turn the input string into an array of integers representing commands.  However, since the compiler will be outputting an arbitrarily large number of commands, and since arrays in Arduino need to be initialized with a length, this could be a problem.

I am not fluent in Arduino so I am hoping that an Arduino whiz can show me a quick solution.  I have already come up with the suggested solution on my own in Python, however, my solution in Python has to do with the ability to change the length of lists on the fly.

You will also notice that I posted the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303582/simple-compiler-design-help-variable-length-arrays-for-c) in the C++ stackexchange.  I am trying to write the same code for an Arduino and in C++.  I know that Arduino code is based on C++, if the answer is the same in Arduino as it is in C++ that would be very helpful.

Comment: Arduino has full c++ language support, but does not have the standard library, so if your c++ answer is "use std::vector<type>" you will need to find or write a separate vector implementation. Outside of implementation, the answers should be the same.

Comment: That's the only answer I've gotten so far.  If that continues to be the only answer then I'll have to find something else for the Arduino

Comment: Do you want to run your compiler **on the Arduino** ? That seems a bit odd.

Comment: Yes I do.  I want to be able to insert an SD card with the code and I want the arduino to compile it.

Comment: Posting the same question on multiple sites is not permitted.  Arduino **is** C++, but beware you have fairly extreme memory limitations.  Ordinarily one would want to do any compiling on the device where the text is being provided, and put only the distilled result into the limited resources of the traditional Arduino board.

Comment: Do you want the arduino to run the code afterward? You can't edit code memory while running on an AVR. What you may want instead is to write a very simple interpreter for some language you write to the SD card.

Comment: If you want to compile and run code from Arduino to Arduono, then the answer is simple: you can't. What you can potentially do however is parse a command line and get a series of lower-level instructions (a kind of `bytecode` like in Java) and then interpret them. But that's quite complex work, though.

Comment: I'm curious now: does Arduino support dynamic memory allocation with pointers like in standard C++?

Comment: @jfpoilpret, I don’t think the answer is that clear cut: First, every Arduino boot loader can and does modify program memory. Second, a compiler could compile to byte code in RAM, instead of machine code.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin yes it does, but because RAM is so scarce, the use of dynamic allocation is extremely rare. I think there might be only a single malloc in all Arduino libraries: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/3a8ad75bcef5932cfc81c4746a87ddbdbd7e6402/libraries/SD/File.cpp

Comment: @microtherion only code in the bootloader are can write code to the rest of the Flash (I think there are some ugly tricks to work around that but it is NOT advised, event by Atmel I believe). Regarding intermediate bytecode writing to SRAM, actually this is exactly what I was saying!

Comment: @microtherion, there are more locations in Arduino libraries that use dynamic allocation, the first that comes to my mind is `String`, which is why I avoid using `String` like the plague.

Comment: @jfpoilpret sorry about the byte code thing. Should not post when fatigued. I believe you're right about the bootloader restriction, but who says a compiler can't live (at least in part) in the bootloader section. Besides, OP was talking about Arduino Due, to which rather different rules may apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have more luck investigating standard C ways of dealing with this issue, instead of the common C++ methods.

Although it is typically not advised, you can use malloc and free on the Arduino. This allows you to dynamically use memory. I would provide a more detailed code example than below but when using dynamic memory it can be hard to troubleshoot what is going on without the use of a library to simplify the process. I would strongly advise doing a little study and understanding both dynamic memory management, and the repercussions of doing so on the Arduino platform. A solid foundation in this will pay off tenfold in time saved when debugging.

Note that you should check each time that you call malloc that it is successful

These resources might help:

- [Dynamic Arrays](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51010-dynamic-arrays-using-malloc-and-realloc/)
- [Check Malloc Succeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607455/checking-that-malloc-succeeded-in-c)
- [Malloc and Free on Arduino Discussion](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=37796.0)
- [Is it a bad idea?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/682/is-using-malloc-and-free-a-really-bad-idea-on-arduino)

Simple Example:

```
// Make a pointer to your array
someType *A;

// The size of your array, may be changed programmatically.
int arraySize = 5;

// Reserve memory for your array.
A = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(someType));

// Use Array
A[0] = someData;

// Release A's memory when complete.
free(A);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The Arduino IDE features nearly full C++ *language* support (at least for C++03 features).
2. *library* support is limited, but any standard component you need, you should be able to get an open source implementation that compiles.
3. That said, you have **2K** of RAM to work with on an Arduino, so the kind of C++ code you would write for a general purpose computer just won’t get you very far.
4. I could be wrong, but I very much doubt there are full Python implementations for Arduino.

**Edit:** Thanks to Mr. Penguin for pointing out that we’re dealing with an Arduino Due, not an Uno (I had overlooked the OP’s tag). 96K of memory is actually a decent amount to play with, so grab a library implementation like [this one](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus) and use the C++ techniques you wish to use.

Comment: You have 96 KB of RAM on the Due if I remember right, 2K is on the Uno. That still doesn't make it better...

Comment: You probably also have hardware capability to execute-from-ram.  It really changes the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

You question isn't totally clear to me, so this is just a pile of advice:

- I think that you *might* be looking for a `run()` type of command, where you can run any function in code. However, since C++ is a *compiled* language, this is not possible. You can only do this in scripting languages.
- Besides that, you want a variable length array? I haven't been able to confirm that this works with Arduino, but I know in standard C++ it is called *dynamic memory allocation* and you can do this with a pointer.
- As for the string to store your data, where you're heading is wrong if you care about efficiency. I'd go with an array of integers (`unsigned int myData[2] = {1, 290};`) since you can store a *lot* more data in two bytes than you could typing out the function names.

For the "multiple run" function of your language, a simple for loop might work better to save space:

```
for(int x = 5; x <3; x++) {
  //Code here
}
```

---

Another thing you might want to do is store this "code" on a SD card encoded in two characters to yield a number like this:

```
byte valOne = SD.read();
byte valTwo = SD.read();
int outputVal = (valOne << 8) + valTwo;
```

This would solve the whole variable array crisis in the first place.

*End of unorganized thoughts...*

Comment: For a while, "New" wasn't implemented, but it is now. "malloc" and "free" and the like have always been available on arduino for dynamic memory management. I don't use it often because with such a small amount of RAM I'm always worried about memory fragmentation, but I have used it.

Comment: @Brett nice to know! The OP is using a Due, so RAM should be sufficient for most cases.