# Add char at intervals in a String

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to create a function that will take a String as an input, and at every 20 characters, it will instert "\n" so that the string doesn't go off the side of my screen (I'm using an oled with the [SSD1306Ascii library](https://github.com/greiman/SSD1306Ascii)).

This is my code so far, but when I run it nothing appears on the screen (I have another part of the code which passes the string to the funtion):

```
String message = "";
String newMessage = "";

void printMessage(String message) {
  oled.clear();
  if(message.length() > 20) {
    current = 20;
    while(current < message.length()) {
      newMessage = message.substring(current-20, current) + "\n";
      newMessage = newMessage + message.substring(current+1);
      current+20;
    }
    oled.println(newMessage);
  }
  else {
    oled.println(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the variables I have decalered, will change that now

Comment: One problem that strikes me is that if the length of the passed message is 20 or less, `newMessage` will remain empty.

Comment: @DarioP Good point, I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your implementation is fundamentally flawed. In the while loop, when you assign `newMessage` to a `message.substring` you are discarding all the work done in the previous iterations.

Also I would recommend keeping the splitting and the printing separated. The `operator +=` also is very handy here. This code (untested) should implement your original idea in a correct way

```
String splitMessage( const String & message, const unsigned limit) {
  String newMessage = "";
  unsigned i = 0;
  while ( i+limit < message.length() ) {
    newMessage += message.substring(i, i+limit);
    newMessage += '\n';
    i += limit;
  }
  newMessage += message.substring(i);
  return newMessage;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
whatever.println(splitMessage(myMessage, 20));
```

---

Note that I retained the use of `String` from your original implementation, although, being in an embedded environment, it is likely better to avoid it in favor of stack-allocated c-strings.

I have found a substantial amount of pretty enlightening information in the various answers to this question: [Is using malloc() and free() a really bad idea on Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/682/is-using-malloc-and-free-a-really-bad-idea-on-arduino)

Comment: Ah, thats far better than what I came up with, thanks. Your code worked perfectly, however I did need to change "message.size()" to "message.length()"

Comment: String object create a memory block at the heap using `malloc()`, dynamically create a String object `newMessage` and return the String object from a function is not a good practise as it could create memory leak in long run because the heap memory for `newMessage` never get free up. For each call to the `splitMessage()`, a new block of memory is created at the heap....

Comment: @hcheung I got you. I am a C++ programmer still getting familiar with the flaws of Arduino "language". Would it be better to return the result through a *non const* reference argument? Like `void splitMessage(String & out, const String & in, const unsigned limit)`?

Comment: As a c++ programmer, you should know the pitfall of `malloc()` and heap usage well. String object behind he scene uses `malloc()` to create a variable when you do something like `String newMessage = "";`, and each iteration of concatenation also cause heap fragmentation. The general idea is not to use String in Arduino (with only 2k RAM), if you really want to use it, in this particular case, I would declare it as a global, so that you can free it afterward, but again, if you are doing it that way, it make not much different to just use c array instead of String object.

Comment: @hcheung as a C++ programmer I always enforce RAII so that the allocated memory is automatically freed when the variable goes out of scope, and I have no further concerns about the heap.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with both your failed implementation and the previous answer
is that they do loads of dynamic allocations and copies. Every time you
use the String’s `+` or `+=` operators you are allocating heap memory
for a brand new String, copying the original character data into the
newly allocated space, and eventually destroying the original Strings
when you don’t need them anymore.

The simplest way to avoid all these copies and allocations is to *not*
build the String you want. Instead, just `write()` the pieces one after
the other on the display. Here is a zero-copy, zero-dynamic allocation
solution:

```cpp
void printMessage(const char *message) {
    size_t length = strlen(message);
    while (length > 20) {
        oled.write(message, 20);
        oled.write('\n');
        message += 20;  // point to the rest of the message
        length  -= 20;  // remaining length
    }
    oled.write(message);
}
```

Note that the method `Print::write(const char *, size_t)` is used here
to print a slice of the message without ever building it as a string in
memory.

On these memory-constrained devices it is always preferable to avoid
heap allocation, and thus `String` objects. However, if for whatever
reason you *really* need to print a `String` object, then you can use
the following overload to print it’s internal buffer without making any
extra copy:

```cpp
void printMessage(const String &message) {
    printMessage(message.c_str());
}
```